# Switch only windows of the same workspace Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome

Here is my setup. Ubuntu 18.04, I have 2 workspaces, each of it has a chrome windows. Everytime I go Super + 2 it prompts to choose the window, while I want to be switched to the window of the current workspace.

Alt + Tab works as expected.

In the Gnome version on Debian it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For this behaviour, run: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true`.

To further ungroup the windows try this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/